# How to make collision in Python Turtle

Tags: python, collision-detection, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to make a collision where when turtle_en touches turtle_h, the game ends. For some reason, turtle distance isn't working. I tried using the distance for the two turtles, but the other turtle just glides right over. I'm not sure what to do anymore, unless it's not possible.

```
import turtle
from random import randint

#Bg

#Introduction
print("Welcome to Turtle Chase!")
player_name = input("What would you like to be called? ")
print("What color do you want your diver to be?")
player_color = input("Choose from red, blue, yellow, or purple: ")
print("Let's Begin!")


#Hero
turtle_h = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_h.penup()
turtle_h.shapesize(2)
turtle_h.setx(-75)
turtle_h.fillcolor(player_color)

#Enemy
turtle_en = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_en.penup()
turtle_en.shape("turtle")
turtle_en.setx(-200)
turtle_en.shapesize(3)
turtle_en.fillcolor("green")

#Goal
turtle_goals = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_goals.penup()
turtle_goals.setx(200)
turtle_goals.sety(-10)
turtle_goals.pendown()
turtle_goals.circle(25)

while True:
  num1 = randint(2, 9)
  num2 = randint(2, 9)
  product = num1 * num2
  response = input(f'What is {num1} * {num2}? (Type "exit" to quit): ')

  if response.lower() == "exit":
      print(f"Goodbye, {player_name}!")
      break

  if response.isdigit():
      if int(response) == product:
          print("Correct!")
          turtle_h.forward(35)
      else:
          print("Incorrect!")
          turtle_en.forward(35)
  else:
      print("Please enter a valid integer answer.")
```

Comment: I don't see any distance checks in your code. Please share the code with the distance check. If you're using a large forward step and the distance check only happens after the movement completes, you might want to check whether the turtle is anywhere to the right of the destination turtle rather than colliding with it.

Comment: first of all. Nice code, i had fun playing the game. But secondly, as per @ggorlen, there is no distance check or any check that would break the `while` loop other than typing exit.  So you will need to implement this...

Answer (score 0):

I added a simple distance checker into the while loop that checks for the x coordinates of each turtle.

You have to set a "radius" out your choice (I used 50).

here is the piece of code that when added gives you the desired outcome:

```py
  x1 = turtle_h.xcor()
  x2 = turtle_en.xcor()
  # print('possies:', x1, x2, 'diff=', abs(x2 - x1))
  if abs(x2 - x1) < 50:
      print('turtles have collided...')
      break
```

It's actually a really fun game. I have a few rounds playing it afterwards.

Well done...

Comment: `import turtle

turtle_h = turtle.Turtle()


turtle_en = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_en.penup()
turtle_en.shape("turtle")
turtle_en.setx(-200)


input("Press 1 to make Turtle Move")

if 1==1:
  turtle_en.forward(170)

x1 = turtle_h.xcor()
x2 = turtle_en.xcor()
# print('possies:', x1, x2, 'diff=', abs(x2 - x1))
if abs(x2 - x1) < 50:
    print('turtles have collided...')`
The code by itself outside the program worked, but when I put it in the program the enemy turtle still glides over the player. Could it be Replit or something else? Thank you.

Comment: @KennzTrysToLearn, you can make the radius larger.  `  if abs(x2 - x1) < 50:` but changing 50 to 100 for example...

Comment: I tried to increase in radius, but it's still gliding over the turtle. Is it possible to give me a code example? Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place. Thank you

Comment: that piece of code just needs to go **inside the while loop**...  you could put it in front of the first if statement.